# Can we find legendary heavy armor pieces?

Tags: fallout-4

I've realized that all of the legendary stuff that I found are always standard armor pieces.

Is it possible to have for example a " legendary heavy synth chest piece " ?

Comment: Pretty sure I've found some, but it's not named like that. You need to pay attention to its base stats to catch it. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: @Iszi I'm pretty sure you're right. Some of the unique legendary items are heavier pieces of armor. My current character has a Mantis piece and a Black Ops piece on his legs, and they're both heavier than normal.

Comment: Yes, there are definitely "sturdy" legendary armour pieces, but they don't have "sturdy" in the name. If you strip their mods you'll see that the base stats are better than standard. I expect the same is true for "heavy" pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly possible.

The legendary loot pool is based on enemy level, to a certain extent. This is why legendary enemies at the beginning tend to drop a bunch of melee or pipe weapon legendarys, while enemies at the South East of the map will drop Fat Men and Assault Rifles.

The tier of armour dropped is also level based. As such, your best bet is to kill legendary enemies at the South-East extent of the map.

For PC Players: There was a mod on the Nexus that I found some time that adjusted Legendary loot lists so that they would always be relevant and not based on level of the legendary dropping it, but I'm having some difficulty finding it at the moment.